# On Azure, how to redirect all outbound traffic on the same IPs?

Tags: azure, networking

On a Virtual network, we have a load balancer with Virtual machines behind and some others Virtual machines.

I want the all outbound traffic use the same static IP address. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual machines are behind the loadbalancer then they should have the same Outbound IP because of the Loadbalancer's SNAT.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snat

You the are not getting the same IP when behind the loadbalancer it might be because you have a public IP on the NIC attached to virtual machine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the ask of an Azure cloud service where we had a single Public for inbound and outbound access. Unless we had an explicit public IP on the NIC's of the VM's which were referred to as ILPIPs.

So the answer is to have them deployed behind an External load balancer and making sure that the backend pool VM's don't have a public IP.

Note:
1. Be sure to set the Public IP as static
2. Be sure of the SKU as reverting from standard SKU to Basic is delete and recreate